# read text file folder structure data and find sum of root node values using c#.net

Tags: c#, dictionary, streamreader

read text file which contains folder structure data and find sum of root node values using c#.net.

Suppose i have following data in text file,
1st column is parent folder
2nd column is child folder
3rd column is data in MB

D Study 50
study Notes 35
F music 12
Notes asp 25

Need to find sum of MB in root folders

so o/p will be

D 110 
F 12

Note: notes folder in study and study in D so 50 + 35 + 25.

what i did till now is created dictionary and sum thier value, please have look at code below,

```
Dictionary<string, long> allTheThings = new Dictionary<string, long>();

using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\\Read.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string [] splitMe = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        if (allTheThings.Count == 0)
        {
            allTheThings.Add(splitMe[0], Convert.ToInt64(splitMe[2]));
        }
        else
        {
            if(allTheThings.ContainsKey(splitMe[0].ToString()))
            {
                allTheThings[splitMe[0]] += Convert.ToInt64(splitMe[2]);
            }
            else
            {
                allTheThings.Add(splitMe[0], Convert.ToInt64(splitMe[2]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but o/p i am getting is not proper. 
read text file folder structure data and find sum of root node values using c#.net.read text file folder structure data and find sum of root node values using c#.net

Comment: It's very stange that D->Study is 50mb, D->Study->Notes is 35mb, D->Study->Notes->asp is 25 and you try to sum all this subfolders of D when he has only one children that contains only 50mb not 50mb+35mb+25mb...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some structure of folders. You can not add input subfolders size and don't save info about it because later you find that subfolder contains some subsubfolders.

So, this class/structure looks like this:

```
class Folder
{
    internal readonly Dictionary<string, Folder> SubFolders = new Dictionary<string, Folder>();

    internal Folder Root = null;

    internal string Name;

    internal long Size;

    internal long GetSum() => Size + SubFolders.Sum(item => item.Value.GetSum());
}
```

And code:

```
class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y) =>
        string.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public int GetHashCode(string obj) => obj.ToUpper().GetHashCode();
}

...

// You should modify code below for supporting fol->fol and "fol_1 fol_2 30 fol_1 fol_2 45"
Dictionary<string, Folder> allFolders = new Dictionary<string, Folder>(new EqualityComparer());
string[] folderInfo = null;
using (System.IO.StreamReader stream = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Read.txt"))
{
    folderInfo = stream.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}

for (int i = 0; i < folderInfo.Length; i += 3)
{
    Folder folder = null;
    Folder subFolder = null;
    if (allFolders.TryGetValue(folderInfo[i], out folder))
    {
        subFolder = new Folder
        {
            Name = folderInfo[i + 1],
            Size = Convert.ToInt64(folderInfo[i + 2]),
            Root = folder
        };

        folder.SubFolders.Add(subFolder.Name, subFolder);
        allFolders.Add(subFolder.Name, subFolder);
        continue;
    }
    folder = new Folder { Name = folderInfo[i] };
    subFolder = new Folder
    {
        Name = folderInfo[i + 1],
        Size = Convert.ToInt64(folderInfo[i + 2]),
        Root = folder
    };

    folder.SubFolders.Add(subFolder.Name, subFolder);
    allFolders.Add(subFolder.Name, subFolder);
    allFolders.Add(folder.Name, folder);
}

foreach (var item in allFolders.Where(folder => folder.Value.Root == null))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Value.Name} {item.Value.GetSum()}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @George Alexandria, it working fine :)